# Replacing items in a string by occurrences

Tags: python

I'm working on writing the script for a hangman game in Python. Suppose the computer chooses the random word (string):

```
bb = "artist"
```

If the player enters a guess:

```
a = "t"
```

It is easy to verify whether or not that is in the word `"artist"` and thus whether it is a correct guess or not. Also, it is easy to change the word `"artist"` into gaps of appropriate length:

```
cc = "_ " * len (bb)
```

Where I am having trouble, though, is filling out the gaps for the correct guess. That is, converting the above to:

```
_ _ t_ _ t
```

I've tried playing around with

```
cc.replace()
```

but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: So where is your closest attempt, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: Please come up with better variable names. While writing an answer, I used the wrong ones three times before getting it right, because it's impossible to remember whether `bb` means the target word and `cc` the currently guessed partial word or vice-versa.

Comment: I'd like to mention a different approach: You could replace all not-yet-guessed-letters in the solution by `_` :)

Answer (score 0):

`cc.replace` isn't going to help you here, because `replace` doesn't have any way to distinguish between one `_` and another `_`, which is exactly what you're trying to do: you want to replace the ones that are *at the same position* as `'t'` letters in `bb`.

"At the same position" pretty much inherently means you're going to be either working by indices, or using `zip`.

If you didn't have the spaces in `cc` that aren't in `bb`, this would be easy. Either of these:

```
cc = ''.join(a if bb[i] == a else cc[i] for i in range(len(cc)))
cc = ''.join(a if b == a else c for b, c in zip(bb, cc))
```

I think the second one is simpler, but…

Unfortunately, you've got those spaces in `cc` that aren't in `bb`. So, the elements of `cc` don't line up with the elements of `bb`; the even ones line up with the `bb` elements at half the index, and the odd ones are always spaces. So, you pretty much have to use the indices to do that, and it's ugly:

```
cc = ''.join(a if (i % 2 == 0 and bb[i//2] == a) else cc[i]
             for i in range(len(cc)))
```

I think you'd be better off *not* storing the spaces in `cc`. For that matter, there's no reason `cc` has to be a string instead of a list. Just do this:

```
cc = ['_' for _ in bb]
```

Then, to update it:

```
cc = [a if b == a else c for b, c in zip(bb, cc)]
```

Then, to turn it into the string that you want to print out:

```
print(' '.join(cc))
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29703843/4669462) explained, you shouldn't be using `cc.replace()`.

A simple solution would be to start off using a list for `cc` and then make use of the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
bb = "artist"
cc = []
[cc.append("_") for x in bb]         #make cc a list of "_" with the same length as bb

while ''.join(cc)!=bb:               #while cc does not equal bb
    a=raw_input("Enter letter: ")    #here, use input() if you use Python 3

    for index,val in enumerate(bb):  #this checks the index and value of bb
        if val==a:                   #if the letter matches the input
            cc[index]=val            #replace the list element with the input

    print ' '.join(cc)               #now you can print the list with spaces and repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `re`

```
import re
bb = 'artist'
>>>re.sub("[^t]","_",bb)
'__t__t'

>>>re.sub("[^t]", "_ ", bb)
'_ _ t_ _ t'
```